# pip install bitarray

Tags: python, pip

Running `pip install bitarray` results in a fatal error for me:

```
bitarray/_bitarray.c:9:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm running an **Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade**. Perhaps I missed installing some dependencies?

Running Python works:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the very least, you will need the python-dev package

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: On RedHat systems this package is called python-devel.

Comment: On centos using YUM we need to run

`$ sudo yum install python-devel`

Comment: for a specific version of Python 3, replace x with the minor version in `$ sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev`

Comment: Im still getting this issue in centos even after installing python-devel.